# One To One unidirectional

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I don't know if this is possible at all, I've been searching a lot for it but i couldn't find an answer.

Say I have two tables, `Parent` and `Child`.

I would like to map the `Parent` entity in such a way that it contains a reference to the `Child` entity, but the `Child` entity doesn't need to know about the `Parent` entity. Ideal mapping should be like this:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "parentSeq", sequenceName = "parentSeq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "parentSeq")
    @Column(name = "id_")
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToOne   // ??
    private Child child;
    
    // getters & setters
}

@Entity
public class Child {
    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;
    
    // has no back reference to the Parent entity
    // getters & setters
}
```

I could share the PK of the `Parent` table to the `Child` entity and make it PK and FK in the `Child` table if that could help, or in general i could modify the DB tables as needed in order to achieve this. Worst case scenario I can have a PK for the `Child` table and a FK to the `Parent` table. However I would not like to have a FK on the `Parent` table to the `Child` table.

The desired behavour would be:

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
Child child = new Child();
child.setName("childName");
parent.setChild(child);
parent.save();
```

So, in the case of a shared PK, the correct way to do this (AFAIK) is to first insert the `Parent` row, then get its Id and use it to insert a new `Child` row with that Id.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Hibernate version is 5.4.28 Final, JPA version 2.1

Thank you

---

Update:

Just to clarify, best scenario for the db structure would be like this:

`Parent` table:

1. Id     (Pk)
2. Name

`Child` table:

1. Id     (Pk, Fk reference Parent Id)
2. Name

Another acceptable solution however would be:

`Parent` table:

1. Id     (Pk)
2. Name

`Child` table:

1. Id     (Pk)
2. Name
3. ParentId (Fk reference Parent Id)

Again, I would like to have a unidirectional mapping from `Parent` to `Child` but according to the link [provided by Davide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one) this seems impossible.

Comment: I can never understand this: if you want for `Child` to know nothing about its `Parent`, why would you want the `CHILD`'s table to have the `PARENT`'s id?

Comment: Because I'd like to keep the foreign key in the `Child` table but I don't need a bidirectional mapping between the `Parent` and `Child` entities. If this was a `OneToMany` relationship mapping I could've use the `@JoinColumn(name="parentId")` annotation in the `Parent` entity to reference the FK in the `Child` entity. I need the same exact thing but in a `OneToOne` relationship and I don' know how to do it.

Comment: I understand *what* you want, I just don't understand *why*. I believe the reason why `@OneToOne` creates the FK in the parent table by default is because it's more performant and flexible. Of course, I don't know your exact use case, so please take my comment with a grain of salt

Comment: Honestly I've seen this "configuration" if you will many times, i don't think is so uncommon but i'm not an expert. From your link I found [this](http://websystique.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-unidirectional-with-shared-primary-key-annotation-example/) which is pretty much what i was looking for. Unfortunately it explicitly set the `Child`'s Id from `Parent`'s Id which is kinda ugly imo.. For now this is the closest solution to i'm looking for. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you should first save `Child` and then `Parent`, but as long as they are managed by the session, Hibernate ORM will execute the operations in the right order when the transaction is committed.

I'm not sure what's the problem you are having, what you are describing is [a classic unidirectional one-to-one](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one)

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

  ...

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "child_id")
  private Child child;
`
  ...
}
```

This mapping implies that there is a column `child_id` referencing a `Child` in the table representing a `Parent`.

Techincally, you need to insert first the `Child`, but as long as the session manages the `Child` and the `Parent` and you insert both in the same transaction, Hibernate ORM will execute the operations in the right order.

An insert will look something similar to:

```
        Session session = ormFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Child child = new Child();
        child.setId(12);
        child.setName("Child");
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setChild(child);
        parent.setName("Parent");
        session.persist( child );
        session.persist( parent );
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
```

or, you can configure the cascade option:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

  ...

  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "child_id")
  private Child child;

  ...
}
```

and then you only have to save parent:

```
        Session session = ormFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Child child = new Child();
        child.setId(12);
        child.setName("Child");
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        parent.setChild(child);
        parent.setName("Parent");
        session.persist( parent );
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
```

You can also use [the annotation `@MapsId`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-derived) if you want `Parent` and `Child` to share the same identifier:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

  @Id
  public int id;

  @OneToOne
  @MapsId
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_")
  private Child child;

  ...
}
```

Comment: Right above the example 163 of the link you provided:

A much more natural mapping would be the Phone were the parent-side, therefore pushing the foreign key into the PhoneDetails table. This mapping requires a bidirectional @OneToOne association

which is what i needed.. I don't understand why this is not possible. In a OneToMany relationship i can put JoinCoumn(name="...") to refer to the FK in a child table but with a OneToOne relationship it seems this is not possible

Comment: Updated question, hope it is clearer now

Comment: Probably this is a question for the Hibernate ORM  Zulip chat: developers:https://hibernate.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/132096-hibernate-user